# Regualr Expression for C comments

Tags: regular-languages

I hope you can help me right now, I am working on lexical analyzer for C language, I am bit confuse bout the regular expression of C style comments. a regex which can handle both single and multiline comments.

Comment: If this were not already a duplicate, I'd ask: what have you tried and where did you get stuck?

Comment: Could you be more precise? What is your problem ?

Comment: @Raphael there are so many answers to them and none of them is working for me, i want a single regex which can handle both single and multiline comments.

Comment: @babou my problem is I have to submit assignment withing 2 hrs! well joke apart my regex is not handling both single and multiline comments in C,  is this regex alright =  (/\*.*?\*/)|//.*?\n "

Comment: @Noor Your homework is your own to do, otherwise you'll learn little to nothing. That said, if you have regular expressions (!= regex, btw) $r_1$ and $r_2$ for both types, joining them like $r_1 + r_2$ should do the trick. (What do you match; the whole text? Lines?)

Comment: Sorry. I do not really have time to test it. It may be a matter of how "newline" may be included in a regexp (I have not written one for quite a while). It may also be a problem with the way you test your regexp, since some processors (without the proper option) will consider only one line at a time, and thus fail if the regexp is not recognized by the end of the line. But I am not making too much sense of your regex (though do not trust me too much).